# Set ; at the end of the line in VIM-MODE-PLUS Atom Editor

Tags: vim, atom-editor, vim-mode-plus

How I have to config Vim so with just pressing (in normal mode) `;` the `;` is set at the end of the line?

So

```
console.log('foo')
```

Becomes

```
console.log('foo');
```

Wherever you have the cursor in the line.

I know the combination would be <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>

Comment: Look up `:help map`. However, in which mode (normal/insert/...) would you want this to happen? Because (personally) it would seem weird in insert mode to have the cursor jump to the end of the line, and `;` is extremely useful in normal mode.

Comment: Sorry @Marth I meant normal mode. Im in `atom` with the `vimmodeplus` plugin activated, `;` does nothing.